# Calling a modal from html

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am unable to get value inside input text when modal is being called from anchor tag.

HTML

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href='#myModal' role="button" data-toggle="modal">${legList.ledgerName} 
    </a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
 aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please enter
 user details</h4>
 </div>
 <form method="post" id="getuserdetails">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <input type="text" name="legid"
 id="legidinput">write something</input>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
    dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>>
 </div>
```

[In image one can see on calling modal "write something" is getting printed next to input box instead inside text box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDUlY.png)

Please help me to get data inside text box and also I wat to know if I want to print some dynamic data which is coming from jsp then how I can get inside text box.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use script language to dynamically add text into modal textbox

```js
$('#btnOpenModal').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){$('#legidinput').val(1)},200);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<a href='#myModal' id="btnOpenModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">${legList.ledgerName} 
    </a>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
 aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
 <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Please enter
 user details</h4>
 </div>
 <form method="post" id="getuserdetails">
 <div class="modal-body">
 <input type="text" name="legid"
 id="legidinput">write something</input>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
    dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Submit</button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: How can I pass dynamic value instead of hardcoded value as 1 inside setTimeout(function(){$('#legidinput').val(x)},200);   where x= get dynamic value on click?

Comment: you should store your dynamic value in your global variable and pass the variable instead of x